# What happens when interrupts are disabled on Intel x86 processors?

Tags: x86, operating-system, intel, interrupt

What happens when interrupts are disabled on Intel x86 processors? Are they queued to be processed when interrupts are enabled or they lost? Assuming a Linux OS.

Comment: Assume they may be lost.  The OS cannot queue iinterrupt requests while interrupts are disabled because its drivers etc. will not be entered.  Any 'queueing' or 'caching' would need to be done by hardware and, while some interrupts may well be latched by the interrupt controller, it would be unwise to disable interrupts for anything other than very short intervals.  For an accurate view of what will happen, refer to the hardware user manuals for the interrupt controller - the software can do nothing if it is not entered.

Answer (score 2):

Hardware (asynchronous) interrupts on PC are trigerred by [8259 controller](https://electronicsdesk.com/8259-programmable-interrupt-controller.html) which sends the signal `INT` to x86 CPU. If the processor has disabled interrupts, CPU doesn't acknowledge this with `INTA` and the request keeps pending until interrupts are enabled again (by instruction `STI` at the end of the following instruction).

So the first hardware interrupt request is queued, but the repeated interrupt requests from the same device are lost if they occured before the first request was serviced.
Pending request can be cleared by PC boot or when some driver reprograms the 8529 controller, but this normally does not happen.

See also [8259 on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_8259).

Comment: This is true but today the main actor is the LAPIC which receives the MSIs and the IOAPIC interrupt requests. But it works similarly to the 8259A for the sake of this question.

Comment: We call this "interrupt coalescing". During the time that interrupts are disabled, all interrupts with the same vector are **combined** into one, but no interrupts are lost.